# Animate a div to go around an object and not through

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, path-finding

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                $('body').click(function(e){
                    $('div').html(e.pageX +', '+ e.pageY);
                    $('div').animate({
                        left: e.pageX,
                        top: e.pageY
                    });
                }); 
            })
        </script>
        <style>
            html, body{
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }

            body:after {
                content: "."; 
                display: block; 
                clear: both; 
                height: 0; 
                overflow: hidden; 
            }
            div {
                display: block;
                float: left;
                height: 60px;
                left: 262px;
                position: relative;
                top: 48px;
                width: 60px;
                z-index: 24;
                background: red;
            }

            span {
                width: 150px;
                height: 400px;
                display: block;
                background: green;
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 92;
                top: 40px;
                left: 120px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <span>&nbsp;</span>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JsBIN:** http://jsbin.com/aqiwiz/2/edit

Hello again stackoverflow!

I have a `div` and sort of like a wall (the `span`). Now the div moves around the page wherever you click it. But the problem is I don't want to get the div to move through the wall. I want it to animate around it and do nothing if clicked on the wall.

How do I get this result using javascript/jquery?

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply a [pathfinding algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathfinding).

Comment: Yes, but is there a javascript libary of some sort wich you can recommand?